# ¿Cómo puedo forzar al usuario a que inicie sesión con social-django?

Tags: django

¿Cómo puedo con social-django forzar al usuario a loguearse?
Este enlace:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}">iniciar sesión</a></p>
```

Me permite autentificar al usuario cada vez que hago click en iniciar, pero siempre me loguea el mismo usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más seguro es que tengas una sesión de twitter abierta y por eso siempre te estas logueando con la misma. Prueba a entrar en twitter, cerrar sesión y probar con otra cuenta. También puede ser que no hayas cerrado sesión en la aplicación en la que te logueas.